# Get voltando vazio nodejs + firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase

Pessoal Preciso de uma ajuda com um retorno de get com node e firebase.

recebo um array vazio.

mas no console.log dentro do foreach imprime correto

> [
>     {
>       cnpj: '03052164798-000179',
>       endereco: 'Av Duque de caxias 99999',
>       nome: 'Testando',
>       tel: '999999999'
>     }
>   ]

```
getEmpresas() {
    let empresas = []

    firebase.firestore().collection('empresa').get().then(snapshot => {

      snapshot.docs.forEach(empresa => {

        empresas.push(empresa.data())
        console.log(empresas)
      });

    })
    return empresas
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Erikson, o get do firebase está sendo assíncrono, com isso você dá o return antes mesmo do array ser de empresas ser preenchido.

Você pode fazer o getEmpresas passar a retornar uma promise, aí quando utilizar desse método, você faz o then do retorno ou usa o await:

```
//Método
async getEmpresas() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let empresas = [];

    firebase.firestore().collection('empresa').get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(empresa => {
        empresas.push(empresa.data());
        console.log(empresas);
      });

      resolve(empresas);
    });
  });
}

//Consumo com then
getEmpresas()
  .then( empresas => {
    console.log(empresas);
  });

//Comsumo com wait
let empresas = await getEmpresas();
```

Uma outra forma, seria fazer o consumo do firebase ficar síncrono com await:

```
async getEmpresas() {
    let empresas = [];
    let snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('empresa').get();

    snapshot.docs.forEach(empresa => {
        empresas.push(empresa.data())
        console.log(empresas)
    });

    return empresas;
}
```

Existem muitas outras formas, dá uma pesquisada sobre async/await, me ajudou muito para casos semelhantes ao seu:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas